# Reduce Bitmap size

Tags: android, bitmap

So, I'm updating an old e-book reader. The problem I'm facing is the size of the bitmaps (the pages). The way it works is: the app downloads a file, extract it, decode it with our DRM then I can access all pages. The thing is, each page its a 35mb bitmap.

I need to reduce this by a lot. I can't convert the file to any other format.

I tried this:

```
byte[] rawBytes = intToByteArray(b.getByteCount());
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4;
Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawBytes, 0,rawBytes.length, options);
```

But the Bitmap keeps returning null, and for what I gathered its when the Bitmap facorty can't decode the bitmap.

So, there is any other way to reduce the impact of this big bitmaps ?

Comment: 35MB Bitmap for a single page?  That's ridiculous.

Comment: Why bitmaps? Can you not compress them prior without needing to do it on the fly?

Comment: Yes, it is. But there is nothing I can do with it. changing the files would require changing the DRM and this will not be done.  So I need to find a way to reduce the size, quality, proportions, scale or wharever. No, I can't do it prior because it need to go through the DRM every time.

Comment: Plenty of Android devices will crash when running your app, as you will run out of heap space. Your de-DRM-ing process needs to not load 35MB into heap, instead doing some sort of a streaming DRM removal to a temporary file on disk. Then, you can use `BitmapFactory` to load in the resulting file, resampling it via `inSampleSize`. That being said, what is `rawBytes` in terms of a file format? PNG? JPEG? GIF?

Comment: The file format is PNG

Comment: When you dump `rawBytes` to disk, do you get a valid PNG? Or is there a bug in your de-DRM logic?

Comment: Ideally you should just prescale everything down, unless you plan to project it onto the side of a building at some point. 35 mb is ridiculously excessive, some of my 1200 page study books filled with graphics don't reach that. BitmapFactory also has scaling methods but like CommonsWare said, you'll run out of memory even with a large heap as current devices usually get 48 mb of room, which is already not enough for transitioning between 2 of your 35 mb pages, but older devices have even less.

Comment: I get a 0kb png file